# Wildfly war deployment get path to resource file

Tags: java, wildfly

I have a web-application which uses an external tool to create reports. This tool needs an absolute path to the template i want to generate the report from.

I deploy the templates as a resource included in my war file.

When using an exploded war I can do something like this which works well:

```
String path = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(resourceFile).getPath();
File f = new File(path);
String absoluteFileName = f.getAbsolutePath();
```

Using the not exploded war this does not work. Is there any chance to do somethin like this?

I do not need the content of the resource, so getResourceAsStream(..) is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to use the `getResourceAsStream()` and write the contents to a known location. You could use something like the following to copy the template in your deployment to a temporary file.

```java
final InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceFile);
final Path f = Files.createTempFile("template", ".txt");
Files.copy(in, f);
final String absoluteFileName = f.toAbsolutePath().toString();
```

If you have a set of known templates you could use a `@javax.ejb.Singleton` `@javax.ejb.Startup` EJB.